# SQL, postgres. I have a csv input file with columns like avg. When i export how do i keep my digits?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, copy

SQL, postgres. I have a csv input file with columns like avg with some values as 5,0 or 6,0. When i export back the file it writes 5 and 6 instead. How do i keep my digits?

Edit: im exporting using COPY

Comment: How do you export it?

Comment: Why using a comma , as a decimal separator? A point . is the default for decimals, also in PostgreSQL.

Comment: yes, mate. it's my typo in the post, sorry for that. in database all working good and with points.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `numeric` datatype. This type keeps the original scale of the input, scale being defined in this context as :  *count of decimal digits in the fractional part* (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE num(n numeric);
INSERT INTO num VALUES (1.0), (2.30);

COPY num TO STDOUT;
```

Result:

```
1.0
2.30
```